# Reduce a sequence in most optimal way

Tags: algorithm

We are given a sequence `a` of `n` numbers. The *reduction* of sequence `a` is defined as replacing the elements `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` with `max(a[i],a[i+1])`.

Each reduction operation has a cost defined as `max(a[i],a[i+1])`. After `n-1` reductions a sequence of length `1` is obtained.

Now our goal is to print the cost of the optimal reduction of the given sequence `a` such that the resulting sequence of length 1 has the minimum cost.

e.g.:

```
1

2

3

Output :

5
```

An O(N^2) solution is trivial. Any ideas?

EDIT1:
People are asking about my idea, so my idea was to traverse through the sequence pairwise and for each pair check cost and in the end reduce the pair with least cost.

```
1 2 3
 2 3     <=== Cost is 2
```

So reduce above sequence to

```
2 3
```

now again traverse through sequence, we get cost as 3

```
2 3
 3       <=== Cost is 3
```

So total cost is 2+3=5

Above algorithm is of O(N^2). That is why I was asking for some more optimized idea.

Comment: Any ideas? Plenty. I'm more interrested in your ideas and where you are stuck.

Comment: do you think a greedy algorithm would work? like, reduce starting from the smallest to biggest. Then the optimal reduction would be the sum of all numbers in the array excluding the smallest one. In the example provided it would be 2+3 = 5

Comment: Not sure if this is homework (or what grasp on algorithms you have), but you can turn this into a graph problem. I did not prove this one, but if you try the greedy method be sure to prove it, but it seems possible since a reduction is defined as `max(a[i], a[i+1])`. Notice that, by this definition, `max(a[i], a[i+2])` is not a valid reduction anyway.

Comment: There is something I don't understand: Why is the cost of the resulting sequence of length 1 of any importance? And how is that defined anyway? You defined cost only for reduction operations, but how is the cost of the resulting sequence defined? (Note that the content of the resulting sequence will always be the same anyway, not matter how we find it.)

Comment: Probably the last sentence should be: _The goal is to define the order of reduction operations such that the total cost of reducing the sequence to length 1 is minimal._

Comment: @RageD: No, not homework. A coding contest problem and contest is over now.

Comment: @jogojapan: It is coding contest problem. I too cant tell its importance!!! :-)

Comment: @SegmentationFault where's the contest? also with this algo you'll ALLWAYS end up with `max(a)` so no need for extra steps and cost will be done in one operation

Comment: @dudeofea: no. what abot this case:
           8 1 9 6 5 1 4 5 5 5 2

Comment: @kaᵠ: hackerrank but over now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`O(n)` solution:**

**High-level:**

The basic idea is to repeatedly merge any element `e` smaller than both its neighbours `ns` and `nl` with its smallest neighbour `ns`. This produces the minimal cost because both the cost and result of merging is `max(a[i],a[i+1])`, which means no merge can make an element smaller than it currently is, thus the cheapest possible merge for `e` is with `ns`, and that merge can't increase the cost of any other possible merges.

This can be done with a one pass algorithm by keeping a stack of elements from our array in decreasing order. We compare the current element to both its neighbours (one being the top of the stack) and perform appropriate merges until we're done.

**Pseudo-code:**

```java
stack = empty
for pos = 0 to length
  // stack.top > arr[pos] is implicitly true because of the previous iteration of the loop
  if stack.top > arr[pos] > arr[pos+1]
    stack.push(arr[pos])
  else if stack.top > arr[pos+1] > arr[pos]
    merge(arr[pos], arr[pos+1])
  else while arr[pos+1] > stack.top > arr[pos]
    merge(arr[pos], stack.pop)
```

**Java code:**

```java
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
int cost = 0;
int arr[] = {10,1,2,3,4,5};
for (int pos = 0; pos < arr.length; pos++)
  if (pos < arr.length-1 && (stack.empty() || stack.peek() >= arr[pos+1]))
    if (arr[pos] > arr[pos+1])
      stack.push(arr[pos]);
    else
      cost += arr[pos+1]; // merge pos and pos+1
  else
  {
    int last = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // required otherwise a merge may be missed
    while (!stack.empty() && (pos == arr.length-1 || stack.peek() < arr[pos+1]))
    {
      last = stack.peek();
      cost += stack.pop(); // merge stack.pop() and pos or the last popped item
    }
    if (last != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    {
      int costTemp = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      if (!stack.empty())
        costTemp = stack.peek();
      if (pos != arr.length-1)
        costTemp = Math.min(arr[pos+1], costTemp);
      cost += costTemp;
    }
  }
System.out.println(cost);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused if you mean by "cost" of reduction "computational cost" i.e. an operation taking time `max(a[i],a[i+1])` or simply something you want to calculate. If it is the latter, then the following algorithm is better than O(n^2):

1. sort the list, or more precise, define `b[i]` s.t. `a[b[i]]` is the sorted list: O(n) if you can use RADIX sort, O(n log n) otherwise.
2. starting from the second-lowest item `i` in the sorted list: if left/right is lower than i, then perform reduction: O(1) for each item, update list from 2, O(n) in total.

I have no idea if that is the optimal solution, but it's O(n) for integers and O(n log n), otherwise.

edit: Realized that removing a precomputing step made it much simpler

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that cost of reduction is defined as max(a[i],a[i+1]) i.e. reducing sequence 2,3 has cost max(2,3) i.e. 3

Comment: well, then you can just replace O(1) in step 3 with O(K) with `K=max(a[i])` and you get a O(n log n +n K) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Greedy approach indeed works.

You can always reduce the smallest number with its smaller neighbor.

**Proof**: we have to reduce smallest number at some point. Any reduction of a neighbor will make the value of neighbor at least the same(possibly) bigger, so operation that reduces minimal element a[i] will always have cost c>=min(a[i-1], a[i+1])

Now we need to

1. quickly find/remove smallest number
2. find its neigbors

I'd go with 2 RMQs on that. Doing operation 2 as a binary search. Which gives us O(N * log^2(N))

**EDIT:** first RMQ - values. When you remove an element put some big value there
second RMQ - "presence". 0 or 1 (value is there/isn't there). To find a [for example] left neighbor of a[i], you need to find the greatest `l`, that `sum[l,i-1] = 1`.

Comment: Doing a binary search assumes the list is sorted, in which case the optimal solution is to merge the first two entries (or last two is the sequence is decreasing).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a lot of time when writing the answer. Implication was: do a binary search over second rmq.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't consider it cheating to sort the list, then do it in `n log n` time and then merge the first two entries recursively. The total cost in this case will be the sum of the entries minus the smallest entry. This is optimal since

1. the cost will be the sum of `n-1` entries (with repeats allowed)
2. the `i`th smallest entry can appear at most `i-1` times in the cost function

The same fundamental idea works even if the list isn't sorted. An optimal solution is to merge the smallest element with its smallest neighbor. To see that this is optimal, note that

1. the cost will be the sum of `n-1` entries (with repeats allowed)
2. entry `a_i` can appear at most `j-1` times in the cost function, where `j` is the length of the longest consecutive subsequence containing `a_i` such that `a_i` is the maximum element of the subsequence

In the worst case, the sequence is decreasing and the time is `O(n^2)`.